# The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: linux-mint, repository, r

My computer has Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa with R version 3.6.3. I am trying to do `sudo apt-get update` and I am having this error:

```
Err:21 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:9000:2045:e400:6:c2d3:f940:93a1 443]
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

Also, I would like to install appropriate drivers but I am also getting this error:

```
E:The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Could someone help me? I remember that I had a problem upgrading R, but I am not sure what happened with Release. R now is working normally I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The R repository has separate `bionic-cran35` and `bionic-cran40` for R 3.5 and R 4.0 respectively. If you are using R version 3.6.3 on Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa, which is based on Ubuntu Bionic Beaver, you have to change the entry for R repository, which has to be in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or one of the `.list` files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory, to:

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/
```

In your case, you need to replace `bionic stable-cran35/` with `bionic-cran35/` in your sources line for the R repository to make it as above.

You should be able to go in applications menu to Administration > Software Sources > Additional Repositories and edit your existing entry there.

Assuming that the entry is located in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list` as you indicated, you can also edit it from command line with a text `editor` like `nano` like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list
```

Navigate to the entry with arrow keys, and correct it, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, enter `y`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and exit editing.

Unlike editing an existing entry, when adding the entry for the first time, editing the file manually seems to be the only way. `add-apt-repository` and the graphical interface at Administration > Software Sources fail with "Malformed input, repository not added." In Debian, the package `software-properties-common` provides an abstraction for apt repositories, but in Linux Mint they replaced it with their own `mintsources`, which refuses to add such entry, but accepts editing it.

I assume that you already have the repository key installed. You need to install it if `apt` complains that the public key is not available:

```
Err:7 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease                                               
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9
…
W: GPG error: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

For security, I advise to install keys [only according to the official documentation](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/). I provide here the command from the [README](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/fullREADME.html), which I tested, only for your convenience:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

Tested on a fresh installation of Minux Mint 19.1 Tessa.